# Android Live Wallpaper is blank on device

Tags: android, debugging, live-wallpaper

I recently created my first android live wallpaper and it would not work on friends' devices, however it would work perfectly on my device.

When a friend would load the signed, aligned apk, android would not render the wallpaper and instead would sit at a blank screen.

I was stumped by this issue for several days, however i found the answer and i wanted to share it with the internet incase others run into this problem also.

If you have used the android debugger in your live wallpaper, you will have used

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

My problem came from the apk other people were using was waiting for the debugger, and since their androids were most likely not connected to a computer with eclipse and adb running, the wallpaper waited indefinitely.

Wallpaper Engine initialization fixed code:

```
SonicEngine() {
                    //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Initializing Sonic wallpaper!");
                    /* Initialization stuff */
            }
```

After commenting or removing the wait for debugger call, the service will procede and render successfully on all devices.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you have the answer for this issue then please also post an answer with the solution and accept it so the question will become answered.

Comment: Since, my account is new, i cannot post an answer to my own question for 8 hours, sorry. Will post as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SonicEngine() {
                //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                Log.i(TAG, "Initializing Sonic wallpaper!");
                /* Initialization stuff */
        }
```

Must make sure to comment or remove waitForDebugger() when actually releasing your live wallpaper or it will hang at that point.